# using Wordpress to create pages for hosted version of ShareTribe

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, sharetribe

I have my domain hosted by the hosted version of ShareTribe. But their customization options are limited and I want to use WP&theme to create landing and other new pages while still using their core P2P solutions. I know I can redirect the URL to WP-created pages. How do I combine ShareTribe with Wordpress and hosting pages on Wordpress since I have stuff hosted on ShareTribe already? Are there documentations or links talking about this? For example, my ideal setup is:

-www.mymarketplace.com: redirect to my landing page (e.g. www.mymarketplace.com/mainpage), hosted using Wordpress

-blog.www.mymarketplace.com: blogging page, hosted using Wordpress

-listing.mymarketplace.com: listing page, hosted at ShareTribe.

-signin.mymarketplace.com: signup/signin page, hosted at ShareTribe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you would be able to do this via your domain settings. As the examples you have mentioned, all seem to be sub-domain of your primary domain (mymarketplace.com). You can redirect or point your sub-domains via your domain control panel to desired and different hosting environments. But where would your primary domain point to, like where would mymarketplace.com would point to? (www.mymarketplace.com is technically sub-domain of mymarketplace.com). Also, blog.www.marketplace.com seems to be a bad idea. It should ideally be blog.mymarketplace.com.

Comment: My domain (mymarketplace.com) should point to my landing page created via Bluehost Wordpress, then linking to other subdomains either hosted at ShareTribe or Bluehost Wordpress.  My issue is how do I create new WP pages since the domain is connected to my marketplace on Sharetribe? Bluehost doesn't allow me to create WP pages anymore since the domain is connected to ShareTribe.  Thanks in advance.